# ImportError: libcblas.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, unix, scikit-learn

I am new to unix. I am using sklearn package for python for a multi-class and multi-label text classification. After running

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
```

I get the error

ImportError: libcblas.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have no idea how to solve this error. I have looked at similar question on different forums, but the responses are too advanced for me. Can someone explain in the layman's words, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing the scikit-learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade or install again the sklearn 0.18.1 module.

the following works fine in sklearn 0.18.1 version (this is the latest).

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
```

To see your version do:

```
import sklearn

print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
```

To install sklearn 0.18.1 use:

```
 pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: You use a server or a personal computer? If server, ask the admin to update the module.

Comment: Thanks @sera. After uninstalling and reinstalling a couple of times, it is working properly now.

Comment: Glad that I helped. You can mark the answer as accepted if you solved your problem so that other can try it if thy have the same problem